# How to tell Maven to ignore a dependency if failed to resolve it?

Tags: maven

I have a dependency which I have installed in Maven local repository and is being used locally but is not available on deployment server. I use that dependency using `Class.forName(...)` so there will be no problem if it's missed from classpath on deployment server.

Is there any way to tell Maven to ignore a dependency if it failed to resolve it?

I doesn't seem that `<scope>` or `<optional>` can solve this problem, but it may be possible to do it with `<profiles>` if there is any way to activate/deactivate a profile based on dependencies availability.

Comment: Have you looked at this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720768/ignore-maven-dependency-during-specific-execution-phase

Comment: @Stephan Thanks, I have found maven profiles cleaner to get around this in different environments.

Comment: Profiles work really well to have multiple, separate build environments. We use this at work because our build server hosts `system` dependencies in a different location than local does.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Once dependency is declared - either in common part or in an active profile - it must be resolvable when Maven attempts it; otherwise the build fails.

If maven allowed the requested behavior, the reproducibility of build would suffer a lot.

If obscurity and irreproducibility is not an issue for you, here is a hint how to do it:

- call external ant from your pom.xml, using either exec-maven-plugin or maven-antrun-plugin
- in the ant code, use [artifact:dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/dependencies.html) from Maven Ant Tasks
- wrap it in ant-contrib's [trycatch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) block

In any case, I strongly discourage including such things into maven build. Having it as separate functionality, invoked via ant from commandline, might often be enough.

Comment: As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line) maven is also used to just get some information. However, this fails if a dependency can not be resolved. E.g. to perform a release you could modify the pom.xml or maven.config and set the new version. If you want to verify that now maven is using that version you may want to call `mvn -q exec:exec -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.version}'` but this will then fail what is a pitty.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the missing dependency is only important in the local environment you can use a combination of profile and activation via your .m2/settings.xml

You remove the dependency from your general dependencies and move it as a referenced dependency into a profile of your pom.xml (Project level profile) and activate the profile through your m2/settings.xml.

You may also remove the dependency completly from your pom.xml and move the dependency into a profile which resides in your .m2/settings.xml (User level profile)

see the [introduction to profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) section

another way which fits your needs maybe better

The activation of the above mentioned profile based on the presence of the file in `.m2/repository/local/dependency/1.0.0-Snapshot/local.jar`

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <exists>/home/user/.m2/repository/local/dependency/1.0.0-Snapshot/local.jar</exists>
      </file>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I know how to use profiles as you can see in my question and my comment under my question.

Comment: I added the file based activation of the profile which should help you further.

Comment: It's not a cross system solution. I have even tried this with maven properties (before asking this question) but for some reason which I couldn't figure out it didn't work.

Comment: By cross system you mean different platforms (*nix, windows, etc.) or different local developer machines (different absolute paths)?

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, I had a problem with maven where it would say "cannot resolve dependency" (of some weird transitive dependency that didn't exist anymore), but it only failed with that error message if my `~/.m2/settings.xml` had a

got my jars from a local repository

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>a name</id>
          <url>http://somewhere/local/a</url>
        </repository>
```

If I changed it to mirror, it would not fail.

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>a name</id>
      <name>an awesome description</name>
      <url>http://some/where/local</url>
      <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
```

(same repo).  Go figure.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to exclude the dependencies from the POM

```
<executions>
<execution>
<id>***failed dependency Id***</id>
</execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: An execution ID is neither a dependency ID nor an exclusion.