# maven plugins: phase clean, Could not resolve dependencies

Tags: maven

There's this task:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <delete dir="src\test\resources\templates" includeemptydirs="true" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is: when I run `mvn clean`, `<phase>clean</phase>` tells maven to download project dependencies (that don't exist yet) and I get `Could not resolve dependencies` error.

How to tell maven not to require project dependencies to run this plugin?

Comment: It may not be the plugin. Perhaps, there are some dependencies are not satisfied. Did you see no dependencies in `effective-pom`?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5126223/367285)

Comment: Nishant: it shouldn't ask for dependencies to clean!